# Sequence in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sequence

Write a single  MATLAB  expression  to  generate a vector that  contains **first    100 terms** of  the following   sequence:       **2, -4, 8, -16, 32, …**

My attempt :

```
n = -1 
for i = 1:100 
    n = n * 2 
    disp(n)
end
```

The problem is that all values of n is not displayed in a single (1 x 100) vector. Neither the alternating positive and negative terms are shown. How to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are having a geometric series where r = -2.

To produce 2, -4, 8, -16, 32, type this:

```
>>-(-2).^[1:5]

 2, -4, 8, -16, 32
```

You can change the value of 5 accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Though there are better methods, as mentioned in the answer by @lakesh. I will point out the mistakes in your code.

1. By typing `n = n * 2`, how can it become a vector?
2. By doing `n=n * 2`, you are going to generate -2, -4, -8, -16, ...

Therefore, the correct code should be:

```
n = -1 
for i = 2:101 % 1 extra term since first term has to be discarded later 
    n(i) = -n(i-1) * 2;
    disp(n)
end
```

You can discard first element of `n`, to get the exact series you want.

```
n(end)=[];
```